# python 3.5 matplotlib contour plot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, contour

Trying to add a legend to my contour plot:
[image]

Here is the relevant code part i am having problem with:

```
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contourf(gg, cc, zz_miss)
CS.clabel()
lbl = CS.cl_cvalues
plt.xlabel('gamma')
plt.ylabel('C = 1 / lambda')
plt.legend((lbl), loc= 'upper right')

plt.show()
```

The legend labels of the legend are correct, but why are the pertineent colors all smeared and out of place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's putting the literal polygons of your contour plot as they were markers. It's a problem.

I advise you to create a manual replacement for the color legend. Here is the modification you need to make into your code (generated synthetic data):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(range(100),range(100))
gg = np.sqrt(xx*2+yy*2)
CS = plt.contourf(gg) #, cc, zz_miss)
proxy = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1,fc = pc.get_facecolor()[0]) for pc in CS.collections]

plt.legend(proxy, [str(i) for i in range(8)])
plt.xlabel('gamma')
plt.ylabel('C = 1 / lambda')

plt.show()
```

, the result is this:

[image: Manually building the color legend of contourf]

Answer (score 4):

Thanks.
Also, found a slightly easier one: [see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECojB.png)

```
CS = plt.contourf(gg, cc, zz_miss, alpha= 1)
nm, lbl = CS.legend_elements()
plt.legend(nm, lbl, title= 'MyTitle', fontsize= 8) 
plt.xlabel('gamma')
plt.ylabel('C = 1 / lambda')
```

here is the result: